# Cost data from Adwords to Analytics in multicurrency is not correct

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have come across quite a peculiar issue. In one of my Google Analytics accounts, I have it linked together with two different Adwords account. All good so far.

The issue is that one of the Adwords accounts is in dollars (***which cannot be changed***), and the other one in my local currency. Looking at my Google Analytics reports, I am currently seeing the Adwords cost as my local currency for both, which is totally wrong.

Let me give an example:

$1 is, let's say, roughly worth 10 in my local currency.

So, given that I spend $150 in my Adwords account, it would show up as 150SEK in my GA-reports (SEK being my local currency). It should in fact be 1500 since the Adwords spend is in dollars, and there is no conversion done between the two systems with a mismatching currency.

Does anyone know how I can see the correct spend inside my Google Analytics account, seeing as the two Adwords accounts are using different currencies; SEK and dollars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it imports the value only and will show the currency selected in Analytics. The 150 comes from AdWords, SEK is the currency in Analytics, so it'd show 150SEK.

Not many references in other help forums (I was trying to find some discussion that would help confirm my guess :) but I found this [little snippet](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=B-kjsG-vTowC&lpg=PA105&ots=K0YVM_1gK7&dq=importing%20adwords%20multiple%20currencies&pg=PA105#v=onepage&q=importing%20adwords%20multiple%20currencies&f=false) which mentions that the currency and timezone must match.

Answer (score 1):

GA supports [multi-currency](http://analytics.blogspot.gr/2013/02/multi-currency-e-commerce-support-in.html) however it is only for e-commerce metrics. You could upload data using the [Cost Data Upload](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/cost-data-overview) but "This feature is intended for non-Google paid campaigns. To import Google AdWords data, link your Google AdWords and Google Analytics accounts." All in all you cannot have cost data for two currencies in one view, however you could link the one account to a separate view (with the correct currency setting)